# Pegar dados de um db em uma classe no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

bom dia, estou fazendo um carrinho de compra e nele tenho uma função pra listar os produtos, e me retornar uma array para depois eu listar no meu view mais não sei se seria o correto eu fazer isso na minha classe ou dentro de um model e de um controller, mais o que preciso é pegar os dados do banco preciso saber se é possível fazer direto na classe ou tenho que fazer com model e controller. desde de já muito obrigado a todos os amigos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, primeiramente, como boa prática do MVC, é sempre melhor tratar as informações que vem do banco nas classes Model. Dá pra fazer no controller? Dá. Se vale? Acho que não. O melhor é criar um método select na tua model que retorne pro teu controller. Dessa forma, em outros controllers que tu precise daquela mesma informação, basta buscar no model pelo método e ela já vem pronta.